# Airflow: Why my DAG does not run on expected day

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I created a task that I wish to run at 17:00 from Monday to Friday.

```
dag = DAG(
    dag_id='dummy',
    schedule_interval="00 17 * * 1-5",
    start_date=days_ago(2),
    default_args=args,
    tags=['test']
)
```

But it doesn't run as expected.
I did a lot of research online and I noticed that "airflow schedule tasks at the END of scheduling period". Unfortunately I still couldn't understand how airflow schedule the tasks. I my case, does that mean airflow scheduler will start at 17:00 on Monday but run the job on Tuesday? If that is true, will it work if I changed the schedule_interval to "00 17 * * 0-4"

Comment: Same problem. It seems to work Tue-Fri, Sat and Sun are intentionally off, and Mon it _just skips_. Any guess? Would that be bug in Airflow?

Answer (score 2):

Airflow 2.2 has introduced [Timetables](https://www.astronomer.io/guides/scheduling-in-airflow) to help you get the effect you're looking for. 1-5 should get you a run at the times you expect except the execution_date will be  for the previous day (a run that occurs on Friday will have Thursday's date and a run that occurs on Monday will have Friday's date).

Comment: Unfortunately we are running Airflow 2.1 and upgrading is out of my control. :(  Thank you though!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Reading [7 common errors to check when debugging Airflow DAGs](https://www.astronomer.io/blog/7-common-errors-to-check-when-debugging-airflow-dag/) the first mention is exactly this, i.e.

> an Airflow DAG will execute at the completion of its schedule_interval, which means one schedule_interval AFTER the start date. An hourly DAG, for example, will execute its 2:00 PM run when the clock strikes 3:00 PM. This happens because Airflow can’t ensure that all of the data from 2:00 PM - 3:00 PM is present until the end of that hourly interval.

This suggests such *odd* behaviour is by design. As mentioned elsewhere, Airflow upgrade and using Timetables is the correct way to deal with this.

In case you can't update, I think your solution should be `0 17 * * 0-5` and expect that the first one will be skipped.